# Twitter OAuthにおけるoauth_token_secret (refresh token?)の存在について

Tags: ios, android, ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth

現在、あるアプリでTwitterログインを実装しています。

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth
を見たところ、Twitter側ではOAuth 1.0aをつかっているそうです。

oauth_tokenを使って、Twitter側のAPIを叩ける用になるのはわかるのですが、
oauth_token_secretは何に使うのでしょうか？

refresh tokenという位置づけなのでしょうか？もしそうだとしたら変だなと。
Twitterではtokenに有効期限はないとのこと。となると、refresh_tokenとして使うシチュエーションがない気がします。

となると、OAuth認証という観点ではoauth_tokenだけでいいはずなのに、
oauth_token_secretはなんで存在しているのでしょうか？

facebookでの同様フローでのtokenは一種類だけですし。
英語でもぐぐったのですが、解説してるページが見つからずここで質問させていただきます。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth2 では(httpsを前提にしているので)access_tokenをリクエストに付与するだけでいいのですが、OAuth 1.xではシグネチャを生成してやる必要があります。(非暗号化通信で漏れても正当性が検証できるため)

一方で、　OAuth 1.x にはトークンの更新という概念は存在しない (かったはず)なので、Refresh tokenに該当するものは存在しません。

Facebookの場合は OAuth 2 を採用しているのでフローがシンプルですよね。

[[PHP] ライブラリに頼らないTwitterAPI入門 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/b59d3ce03f08be126000)

Comment: ありがとうございます、しっくりきました！